# Windows 8.1 Hub and add items in runtime

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I want create a hub on Universal App (Windows/Windows Phone 8.1) like this image:
[image: list]

I want add items in Runtime by c# code without any binding( microsoft sample is for binding and XAML) and every item has a Tapping or Clicking event.
how can I do that? I never worked with Hub before that.
thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches you can use:

- The classic one is the one suggested in the documentation: create a DataTemplate in your Hub page, add a ListView inside it and set the ItemClick event aas you want. Then create your own ViewModel for the page, add an IEnumerable parameter to bind the ItemSource to. Then you'll be able to edit that Parameter in code behind and those changes will be reflected in the UI.

The point is that you can't directly access UI elements using x:Name="myName" from code behind when those items are inside a data template, like inside a Hub page.

- A possible solution would be to create a UserControl to place inside the data template of the Hub item.
  Then you'll be able to work on your UserControl directly from code behind, without using Bindings. For example you can simply use a ScrollViewer with a StackPanel inside it. Then you'll be able to programmatically create your list elements, set their events and add them to the StackPanel, eventually with some animations. Or you could use a ListView and manually refresh the ItemsSource parameter with new lists you create at runtime.

Anyways, I really suggest you to create your own ViewModel, and Bind the ListView to your page DataContext, as suggested in the MSDN guide.
The ListView already has a lot of events you can subscribe to for each list item, so that's really the better option you have here.